# First and second moments of recurrence time in a finite two-dimensional Markov chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

I have a two dimensional finite Markov chain with $(m+1)^2$ states, and with transition rates:

$q_x((x,y)\to (x+1,y))=(m-x)\lambda,\quad 0\leq x< m, 0\leq y \leq m$,

$q_x((x,y)\to (x-1,y))=x\mu,\quad 0 <x\leq m, 0\leq y \leq m$,

$q_y((x,y)\to (x,y+1))=(m-y)\lambda,\quad 0\leq x\leq m, 0\leq y < m$,

$q_y((x,y)\to (x,y-1))=y\mu,\quad 0\leq x< m, 0< y \leq m$,

I need to find the first and second moment of the recurrence time for the set of states $\mathcal{A}$, where $\mathcal{A}=\{ (x,0)\cup (0,y): 0\leq x,y \leq m \}$.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

For the corresponding 1D Markov process, i.e. the Markov process with transition rates: $q(x,x+1)=(m-x)\lambda, 0\leq x<m$ and $q(x,x-1)=x\mu, 0<x\leq m$, the first and the second moments of the recurrence time to state $x=0$ is known. Now I am stuck in finding the recurrence time   to set of states $\mathcal{A}$ in the two dimensional Markov process described above.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please consider updating your question with some information about what you have tried or where you are getting stuck. You will find people are much more willing to help if you do!

Comment: Thanks- I just added more explanation. I hope it makes the problem more clear!

Comment: When you say that the one dimensional case "is known", how is it known? What method do you use to solve it? Why do these methods fail to generalize to the two dimensional case?

Comment: The 1D Markov Process is actually the Enhrenfest process. The Laplace transform of the hitting time of Ehrenfest process is done by Feuillet et. al. in "On the transient behavior of Ehrenfest and Engset processes" by using Martingales. But the derivation of the Laplace transform is difficult for me, and I do not know if it can be generalized to the 2D process or not?